# Can an xml schema validate an element value based on the existence of another element value?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am a newbie with regard to xml/xsd, and would appreciate some counsel on an issue related to validating element values.

I am developing a system to work with courses within a curriculum. A curriculum will consist of a group of courses and each course will have a number of characteristics, including an id.

The prerequisites for a course are id's corresponding to other courses specified in the xml.

Is there a way to validate that an id number in a prerequisite element exists as the course id for another element?

Below is my start at the schema.

Thank you for any advice you can give.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="some relevant uri"
    xmlns:ap="some relevant uri">

  <xs:element name="course">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ap:id"/>
                <xs:element ref="ap:prerequisite" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="id" type=?????>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="prerequisite" type=?????>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with xs:key and xs:keyref. Hopefully knowing the keywords will enable you to find the relevant section in your favourite XML Schema textbook...

The main thing to remember is that these declarations must appear as part of the element declaration for the element within which the constraint applies: If the rule is "within an X, every Y must have a distinct value for Z, and every V must have a value for W that matches the value of Z for some Y (within the same X)", then

- In the declaration of X, define a key with name = N, selection = Y, field = Z
- In the declaration of X, define a keyref with ref = N, selection = V, field = W.

In your example, Y is course, Z is id, V is prerequisite, W is id. I don't know what X is but it's probably the parent of your course elements.